# How do I compile with -g option in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, compilation

When debugging I get an warning message on exception saying `'variable info not available - compiled without -g'` - how do I set to compile with -g in netbeans?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know your *own* code is compiled with debug information.  The Java runtime library, however, *isn't*.

Please double check that the location you see this message, is in your own code and not the runtime library.

Comment: Hi, where is it and how can I check if it is in there or not ? Thanks

Comment: @Thorbjorn Ravn Anderson, How can I see the runtime variables like I can with IntelliJ??

Comment: @cosbor11 please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255474/debug-jdk-source-cant-watch-variable-what-it-is

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this texhnique. However, when I tried doing these steps for the javafxrt.jar many of the classes were missing, including the one I wanted to step through.

Comment: @cosbor11 I do not know if Oracle has a developer specific JDK download which provide what you need.  You may look into the OpenJFX project.  You may consider opening a question with your actual problem.

Answer (score 5):

In my Nb 7.4 there is a "generate Debuging info" flag on
project propertyes -> Build -> compile ;

but if you, like me, are using maven, you have to check in pom.xml too

let me show an example:
you can ave a production profile and in that profile you can have the maven compiler plugin with debug setting to false

```
        <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                        <debug>false</debug>
                        <optimize>true</optimize>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
 ...
```

see the false setting
if you have a similar setting on your pom.xml local variable on debug are not show.