# debug jdk source can't watch variable what it is

Tags: java

I'm debugging the JDK source like:

```
 public static int codePointAt(CharSequence seq, int index) {
        char c1 = seq.charAt(index++);
        if (isHighSurrogate(c1)) {
            if (index < seq.length()) {
                char c2 = seq.charAt(index);
                if (isLowSurrogate(c2)) {
                    return toCodePoint(c1, c2);
                }
            }
        }
        return c1;
    }
```

and I want to see `c1` variable before I step into `if (isHighSurrogate(c1))`.
However, when I debug watch `c1` variable
it display :

[image]

I really have tried added rt.jar source, and it really can step into breakpoint of JDK source, like:
[image]

but why `c1` variable can't display?

Comment: Actually it isn't that difficult at all. See my updated answer

Comment: Why the hack are there no downloads for JDKs with debug information included?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Generally speaking, to be able to watch the variables while stepping through JDK source code, you need the class files to be compiled with debug information i.e. compile using `javac -g`.

So your best bet is to either find an already compiled version with debug information (I couldn't find anything for JDK 7) or you can try compiling the source for yourself.

According to [this post](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19866.html) (please note that I haven't tried it) you don't need to compile all sources, only the ones you need. Putting your newly compiled classes in the `$jdk/jre/lib/`<strike>ext/</strike>`endorsed` directory, the new classes would be used instead the ones in the original `rt.jar`.

I believe that should get you started.

**Update:** Actually I have just tried this process and it is not hard at all. Tested on Windows, JDK 1.7.0_11. All the commands are invoked from command line:

1. Create your working folder. I chose `d:\` root folder
2. Inside your working folder create the source folder i.e. `jdk7_src` and output folder `jdk_debug`
3. From your `JDK_HOME` folder get the `src.zip` file and unzip it inside `jdk7_src`
4. Select what you will compile and delete the rest. For all of them you might need additional steps. I have chosen the folders:

   - `java`
   - `javax`
   - `org`
5. From your `JDK_HOME\jre\lib` get the file `rt.jar` and put in the work folder (this is only for convenience to not specify too large file names in the command line).
6. Execute the command: `dir /B /S /X jdk7_src\*.java > filelist.txt` to create a file named `filelist.txt` with the list of all java files that will be compiled. This will be given as input to `javac`
7. Execute `javac` using the command:
   `javac -J-Xms16m -J-Xmx1024m -sourcepath d:\jdk7_src -cp d:\rt.jar -d d:\jdk_debug -g @filelist.txt >> log.txt 2>&1` This will compile all the files in the `jdk_debug` folder and will generate a `log.txt` file in your working folder. Check the log contents. You should get a bunch of warnings but no error.
8. Go inside the `jdk_debug` folder and run the command: `jar cf0 rt_debug.jar *`. This will generate your new runtime library with degug information.
9. Copy that new jar to the folder `JDK_HOME\jre\lib\endorsed`. If the `endorsed` folder does not exist, create it.

Debug your program in Eclipse. Note how the variables are named normally (no more arg0, arg1 etc). Happy debugging :)

[image: JDK debug]

Comment: thanks very much, and i encounter a problem in item6:dir /B /S /X jdk7_src\*.java > filelist.txt what is /B /S /X?

Comment: `/B`: no additional file info. `/S`: read subdirectories too. `X`: shows the short names of the files instead of long file names. You can see this information if you run `dir /?`.

Comment: Worked great! Excellent response! You can also do this for parts of the Java codebase that aren't included in src.zip, like the SunJCE crypto provider.

Comment: This is great info, but for convenience see @weberjn's answer.

Comment: I just compiled the source code of jdk1.7.0-51 in windows7, got 45 errors "error: cannot find symbol." It seems the package (sun.awt.*) is needed, however does not locate by default in the jdk source code.

Comment: Brilliant! I though't compiling would take ages. It took 3mins on my pc. Now I can see the variables. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @rekinyz same with jdk1.8.0_91 on ubuntu. any solution in sight?

Comment: while doing step7 I am getting this error in log.txt  `javac:invalidflag:   usage:javac <options> <source files>` how to fix this? @c.s.

Comment: @subburoyal What is the command you are using? From the message it seems that either you enter an invalid option or the file with the list of the sources is not recognized (perhaps mispelled?)

Comment: I am using this command `javac -J-Xms16m -J-Xmx1024m -sourcepath "D:\etr\java\debug\jdk_source" -cp "D:\etr\java\debug\rt.jar" -d "D:\etr\java\debug\jdk_debug" -g @filelist.txt >> log.txt 2>&1`      and I am getting this         `javac: invalid flag: D:\etr\java\java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options`  all files are there in the mentioned location. can you plz help me what is the mistake I am doing? @c.s.

Comment: @subburoyal perhaps your filelist.txt was not generated correctly. The message says about a flag: `D:\etr\java\java` which I can only imagine that it finds it inside that file. I would open and examine the file to check if the source paths in there are correct. You might also want to remove any double quotes in all paths. Other than that I can't help much.

Comment: @c.s. Thank you very much, I changed location of `filelist.txt` after creating and I tried step 7, as per ur suggestion I saw the location  by opening `filelist.txt` and I realized that the path is different and compiling in different location. Now I fixed the issue by changing the location to this path `D:\etr\java\debug` once again thank you very much. Now I am able to see the local variable values while debugging.

Comment: I get an emtpy output directory for jdk1.8.0_111 :/

Comment: I tried to same steps for JDK8_101, and I got also empty jdk_debug. I check the filelist.txt and all paths are good. Any idea why to fix it?

Comment: I figured out what was the problem. I have two JDK installed 11, and 8, and I was using JDK11 to build JDK8 source files. Once the correct version is used, it worked.

Answer (score 14):

c-s's jre\lib\endorsed solution is great.
Easier to build is with Eclipse: create a Java project, put javax*, java* into src and let Eclipse compile. Then export the jar.

Comment: I can confirm this works, except that I built the jar using Intellij Idea. Simply put the jar in `$jdk/jre/lib/endorsed` and voila you can debug normally!

Comment: This worked for me in Netbeans as well. I did: *1.* create a new empty project *2.* copy the source files I wanted in to a new folder inside the project directory *3.* add this directory to project source files *4.* clean and build *5.* copy the jar from the `dist` directory to the `endorsed` directory. Worked like a charm.

Comment: This is not an answer by itself; it should be a comment or edit to the accepted answer.

Comment: I was always having errors with javac (recompiling rt of jdk1.8), but it worked flawlessly in Eclipse. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This article http://www.thejavageek.com/2016/04/03/debug-jdk-source-code/ describe the same but in simple and nice way. You do stuff(compile,make jar) by using eclipse only.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, *the endorsed override mechanism is deprecated and will be removed in a future release* (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/standards/).

Use this `pom.xml` to get JDK `1.8.0_111` sources with debug information:

```
<project>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>JDK sources with debug information</name>

  <groupId>ex.jdk.debug</groupId>
  <artifactId>jdk-debug-sources</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.0_111</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>jdk-rt</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0_111</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <debug>true</debug>
          <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>com/sun/java/swing/**</exclude>
            <exclude>com/sun/source/util/**</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

 </project>
```

You'll have to do a manual install of the original `rt.jar` to be able to run `mvn clean install`

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=rt.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=jdk-rt -Dversion=1.8.0_111 -Dpackaging=jar
```

The `rt.jar` I copied to the `endorsed` directory is the original `rt.jar` but with the original classes replaced by my newly generated classes.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody needs this with **tomcat**. You need to set up the VM argument Djava.endorsed.dirs and put your compiled jdk jar in it. You can do this c-s's solution or exported with eclipse(all the Java Compiler ClassFile Generation used by de debugger must be active)

Go to Run Configurations > Arguments > VM arguments

Djava.endorsed.dirs="/your/folder/apache-tomcat-xxx/endorsed"