# Why can't I step through Java API classes?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have set a breakpoint in `String` class. On running the program in debug mode the breakpoint is hit but I cannot step into the code. Pressing `F5` resumes the execution to next breakpoint. I have removed `java.*` package from step filters.

I am using [Groovy grails toolsuite](https://grails.org/products/ggts) instead of vanilla Eclipse.

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**
Eclipse does seem to have source archive:
[image]

Comment: Maybe, unchecking "Filter simple getters" will help?

Comment: @orionll I tried that. Didn't work. Seems to be a bug in GGTS. I tried this in vanilla Eclipse and it works.

Comment: The distinguishing feature of StringCoding is that it is package private ......

Comment: @StephenC I don't understand how accessibility of the Class should affect debugging. And the source for JDK is included in `src.zip`, which is correctly attached to `rt.jar`.

Comment: Possibly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255474/debug-jdk-source-cant-watch-variable-what-it-is

Comment: @KshitizSharma - neither do I.  Nevertheless, that's what is different about it.  Have you checked that the source for that class is in the src.zip file??

Comment: @StephenC Yes the source is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GGTS has step filters on by default.  Go to Preferences -> Java -> Debug -> Step filtering to disable it.  You also may need to go to Preferences -> Groovy -> Debugger -> Extended debugging and disable all preferences there.

Comment: In the question I've clearly mentioned that I've properly configured Step filters. A screenshot is attached.

Comment: Make sure that you also have Extended debugging disabled. By default, it only applies to Groovy projects, but there is an option to turn it on globally.  Disable all of that to be sure.

Comment: I'll check that on Monday morning and let you know. Although I suspect that its something to do with `Grails IDE` plugin as I've mentioned in my answer.

Comment: The only interaction that Grails IDE has in that area is through those options I mention above.

Comment: Your suggestion works. However when I disable extended debugging the Display view stops working. Evaluating an expression gives a NP.

Answer (score 0):

This is a defect in `Groovy Grails Toolsuite` bundle.

I wanted to localize the fault, so I started with vanilla `eclipse` and installed each plugin in the bundle individually until the problem occured. It showed up when I installed `Grails IDE` plugin.

The way to get around this problem is take a vanilla eclipse and install `Groovy Eclipse` and `Spring IDE` separately. This will also make eclipse run faster as it'll avoid other stuff that comes bundled with `GGTS`.