# Want to debug the source code of JDK

Tags: java, debugging, jdk1.7

I have the problem same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255474/debug-jdk-source-cant-watch-variable-what-it-is).

I just tried to figure out how does hashmap internally works. So I want to debug the source code of SDK.

Currently. I think What I am looking for the `compiled version with debug information` for `Java SE 1.7`. i.e. compile using `javac -g`.

[image]

I think I am not the only guy who want to do this. So anyone who knew the link or already done this before. (Sorry for I am the lazy man.Forgive me that. ) Please kindly share the work result for me. Well appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: *compiled version with debug information* -> Do you mean *byte-code*?

Comment: I meant the compile result of `javac -g`. as the link I mentioned in my question suggested. Thanks.

Comment: There is a src.zip file in jdk folder which has the source code for java files. Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, I had made it. Just followed the `jre\lib\endorsed solution`, It works well. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to compile those classes with debugging yourself.

Distributing such a package would probably be a violation of Oracles License Agreement.

The post you linked has detailed instructions on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The link in my question actually answered my question. But I just want to add missed part it didn't mention. The endorsed jar file should be joined in the installed JRE as an external jar otherwise it doesn't work. Thanks.