# How to fix javac: invalid flag: error while compiling rt.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am trying to debug java source code, for this I am using  `JDK's rt.jar`. I am stepping into source code while `debuging`

ex:-

```
Map m = new HashMap();      
m.put(10, "abc");
```

I placed `brakepoint` for `m.put()` and stepping into the sourcecode of `put()` method in `HashMap` but I am unable to see values for `key and value` which I am passing. The problem is `rt.jar` has given without `debuginfo` for this we have to compile the `source code`.

I am trying to compile the `source code` according to this post
[debug jdk source can't watch variable what it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255474/debug-jdk-source-cant-watch-variable-what-it-is)

But while compiling below line

`javac -J-Xms16m -J-Xmx1024m -sourcepath "D:\etr\java\debug\jdk_source" -cp "D:\etr\java\debug\rt.jar" -d "D:\etr\java\debug\jdk_debug" -g @filelist.txt >> log.txt 2>&1`

I am getting the below error in `log.txt`

`javac: invalid flag: D:\etr\java\java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options`

Can anyone help me how to fix the above issue.

Comment: Sure you can see the values of the two parameters. Just look at the `Variables` view in the Eclipse Debugger. The parameters are called `arg0` and `arg1`.

Comment: Yeah, but I am unable to inspect like `ctrl`+`shit`+`i` I am getting `cannot be resolved type`. is it possible to see the values by inspecting them?  @Andreas

Comment: You can see the parameters and the `this` object in the `Variables` view. Isn't that enough, rather than messing with recompiling the JDK?

Comment: Why are you trying to 'debug' HashMap? The chances of there being a problem in JDK code are tiny.

Comment: I doing this because to understand the internals of HashMap. @greg-449