# Linux Debian NetBeans compiling error: Annotation processor '-g' not found

Tags: netbeans, compiler-errors

Bonjour,
When I run Build Project with Netbeans, I have this error:

> error: Annotation processor '-g' not found

Know you how I can correct this error?
Merci

Comment: It appears that you've translated this error message into English from French, so it's hard to tell exactly what it is trying to say. Is this related to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370728/how-do-i-compile-with-g-option-in-netbeans?

Comment: Thanks, problem is going away, I don't know why.....